# Acceleration in an empty universe

Tags: special-relativity, equivalence-principle, machs-principle

Regarding an acceleration in an empty universe, from the special relativity we feel an acceleration in an empty universe since there is still the presence of an space-time with respect to which an acceleration is measured and the equivalence principle says that locally the effect of gravity and acceleration is indistinguishable i.e we feel the gravity whenever we are acceleration and conversely we feel acceleration when there is gravity that means according to equivalence principle we can't feel an acceleration in an empty universe since there is no gravity but special relativity says that we can feel an acceleration in an empty universe ,for me there seems a contradiction between special relativity and equivalence principle. Does anybody make clear this doubt?

Comment: Please rewrite into short intelligible sentences.

Comment: @JánLalinský agreed.  A few commas and periods would make the posting MUCH easier to read and comprehend.

Answer (score 3):

No, you misunderstand the equivalence principle. Acceleration is indistinguishable from the effect of gravity, but that does not mean that the absence of gravity rules out the possibility of acceleration. Gravity is not the only cause of acceleration- other forces can produce it.

Comment: I didn't agree with your answer because in an empty universe where there is no gravitational field, locally a person able to detect that he is in an accelerated frame of reference if the absence of gravity doesn't rules out the possibility of an acceleration which again seems to contradict the equivalence principle.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Suppose you are at rest with a buddy in a region of the Universe where there is no appreciable gravity. If you push against your buddy, you will each float away from each other. How can you account for that if there is no acceleration?

Answer (score 3):

Being bitten by a tiger feels exactly like being bitten by a lion. So if the tigers can't bite you, the lions can't bite you --- right?

Answer (score 1):

One misconception here – we do not feel gravity as acceleration.  We feel *resistance* to gravity (e.g. standing in a suspended elevator on Earth) as indistinguishable from acceleration (e.g. standing in a rocket in space accelerating at 1 g).

Instead of "gravity," it's better to think of "following a geodesic trajectory" in spacetime.  Following a geodesic means traversing your natural path through the local spacetime due to its curvature.  An object in freefall, a satellite orbiting, and a stationary object in your empty universe are all following geodesics. The weightless observer in a box in any one of those scenarios will not be able to tell the difference. *Geodesic* in General Relativity generalizes the concept of *inertia frame* in Special Relativity.

An observer in a closed box could start in interstellar space, be captured into orbit by a passing rogue planet, then have its orbit destabilized by a passing black hole and then fall into the black hole at 90% the speed of light - and he would observe none of this from inside the box (the black hole would kill him, but only because the box would become too big for the field to be uniform.  If he were in an infinitesimally small box, it wouldn't kill him, nor would he notice falling into it).

Deviating from a geodesic means we have a non-zero proper acceleration.  Examples are: standing on Earth's surface (the spacetime curvature wants us to continue towards the center of the Earth), changing orbits by applying thrust, or encountering atmospheric drag and being decelerated.